# Firebase Crashlytics initialization with two environments

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I have a C# Unity project with Crashlytics and I want to have a development and production environment. So I created two Firebase projects for each one. The problem is that I only have the google-services.json credentials document of the production on the project, and all the builds I do point to that environment.

I also use Firestore and I don't have this problem with it. I have found that you can create a FirebaseApp and with this one, you are able to get a FirebaseDatabase instance, as shown below. Is there a way to do the same with Crashlytics?

```
AppOptions opt = new AppOptions()
{
    AppId = XXX,
    ApiKey = XX,
    MessageSenderId = XXX,
    ProjectId = XXX,
    DatabaseUrl = new Uri(XXX)
};
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.Create(opt, "DEV");
FirebaseDatabase fdb = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance(app);
```

I believe that I could detect if a build is a dev or prod build and switch the credentials files, but I think that it is not a good solution, and it will probably cause problems. Am I missing something?
Thanks!

I have not found any documentation regarding this problem.